# Meaning of "ben" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

What would be the meaning of the word "ben" in this sentence:  "Infatti ha **ben** sei figli."

According to the dictionary is "well". That does not make too much sense to me...

Comment: Which dictionary? Ragazzini includes this meaning, and exemplifies it with _ben due milioni_ = “a good (_fam._ cool) two million” and _ben sei mesi_ = “no less than six months”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *bene* (here truncated to *ben* for euphonic reasons) does mean *well*, but in this context is not used in this meaning. It is used as an [intensifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier), to remark on how impressive the number of children is.

After thinking for a while I could not come up with any English word that plays the same role here. So I suggest one to omit it in the translation:

> Indeed he has six children

Comment: Come traduzioni, forse "so much as six children"? O "*six* children" con il corsivo per enfatizzare? Ma il tuo inglese è sicuramente migliore del mio...